# Sequence number of documents saved

Tags: lotus-notes

I use the below script in `querysave` event of a form. The logic is when I save the form the sequence should get displayed in the view in two columns. like "115-" in one column and the sequence "00001", "00002", ... in the second column. The first two documents gets saved without any issue. When I save try to save 3rd and more documents, its displaying "00002" only every time after that. I am not able to identify what is the mistake. Can somebody help please.

```
Sub Querysave(Source As Notesuidocument, Continue As Variant)
    Dim SESS       As New NotesSession
    Dim w          As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc      As NotesUIdocument
    Dim Doc        As NotesDocument
    Dim RefView    As NotesView
    Dim DB         As NotesDatabase
    Dim RefDoc     As NotesDocument
    Set DB      =  SESS.CurrentDatabase
    Set uidoc   =  w.CurrentDocument
    Set Doc     =  uidoc.Document
    Set RefView =  DB.GetView("System\AutoNo")

    Dim approvedcnt As Integer
    approvedcnt = Cint(source.fieldgettext("appcnt"))

    If uidoc.EditMode = True Then 
        Financial_Year =  Clng(Right$(Cstr(Year(Now)),3)) + 104
        If Month(Now) >= 4 Then Financial_Year = Financial_Year + 1
        DocKey     =  Cstr(Financial_Year)& "-"
        New_No      =  0
        Set RefDoc  =  RefView.GetDocumentByKey(DocKey , True)
    If Not(RefDoc Is Nothing) Then New_No = Clng(Right$(RefDoc.SETTLEMENT_NO(0),5))
        New_No      =  New_No + 1
        autono      =  DocKey & "-" & Right$("00000" & Cstr(New_No) ,5)
        Application ="ST"
        Latest_No = Application + autono
        Doc.SETTLEMENT_NO = Latest_No
        Doc.FinFlag="Finish"
    Call SESS.SetEnvironmentVar("ENV_ST_NO",Right$("00000" & Cstr(DefNo&) ,5))
        'Call uidoc.FieldSetText("SETTLEMENT_NO",Latest_No)

        Call uidoc.Refresh
        Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    get_ex_rate
    get_cv_local


    Call uidoc.FieldSetText("Flag1", "A")

    If approvedcnt = 12 And uidoc.FieldGetText("STATUS") = "APPROVE" Then
        Call uidoc.fieldsettext("Flag2", "B")
    End If

    Dim answer2 As Integer

    answer2% = Msgbox("Do you want to save this document?", 1, "Save")
    If answer2 = 1 Then 
        Print "Saving"
    End If  
    If answer2 = 2 Then
        continue=False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    uidoc.Refresh
    uidoc.close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your call to GetDocumentByKey is getting the wrong document or not the next one in sequence.  Make sure the view is sorted properly and perhaps call the refresh method on the view before calling GetDocumentByKey.

Comment: I called the refresh method also. The 3 rd time when i try to save its giving the same previous number. I m really helpless..I have already spent a lot of time on this :(

Comment: You can turn on DebugLotusScript and watch the values as you step through the code.  See if RefDoc is an actual document or comes back as nothing.  Also make sure that AutoNo view is sorted properly and open it to make sure the 00002 is showing after the second save.